# Best Learning model for high numerical dimension data? (with Rapidminer)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-modeling, rapidminer

I have a dataset of approx. 4800 rows with 22 attributes, all numerical, describing mostly the geometry of rock / minerals, and 3 different classes.

I tried out a cross validation with k-nn Model inside it, with k= 7 and Numerical Measure -> Camberra Distance as parameters set..and I got a performance  of 82.53% and 0.673 kappa. Is that result representative for the dataset? I mean 82% is quite ok..

Before doing this, I evaluated the best subset of attributes with a decision table, I got out 6 different attributes for that.

the problem is, you still don't learn much from that kind of models, like instance-based k-nn. Can I get any more insight from knn? I don't know how to visualize the clusters in that high dimensional space in Rapidminer, is that somehow possible?
I tried decision tree on the data, but I got too much branches (300 or so) and it looked all too messy, the problem is, all numerical attributes have about the same mean and distribution, therefore its hard to get a distinct subset of meaningful attributes...

ideally, the staff wants to "Learn" something about the data, but my impression is, that you cannot learn much meaningful of that data, all that works best is "Blackbox" Learning models like Neural Nets, SVM, and those other instance-based models...
how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of machine learning!  This sounds like a classic real-world case: we want to make firm conclusions, but the data rows don't cooperate.  :-)

Your goal is vague: "learn something"?  I'm taking this to mean that you're investigating, hoping to find quantitative discriminations among the three classes.

First of all, I highly recommend Principal Component Analysis (PCA): find out whether you can eliminate some of these attributes by automated matrix operations, rather than a hand-built decision table.  I expect that the messy branches are due to unfortunate choice of factors; decision trees work very hard at over-fitting.  :-)

How clean are the separations of the data sets?  Since you already used Knn, I'm hopeful that you have dense clusters with gaps.  If so, perhaps a spectral clustering would help; these methods are good at classifying data based on gaps between the clusters, even if the cluster shapes aren't spherical.  Interpretation depends on having someone on staff who can read eigenvectors, to interpret what the values mean.

Try a multi-class SVM.  Start with 3 classes, but increase if necessary until your 3 expected classes appear.  (Sometimes you get one tiny outlier class, and then two major ones get combined.)  The resulting kernel functions and the placement of the gaps can teach you something about your data.

Try the Naive Bayes family, especially if you observe that the features come from a Gaussian or Bernoulli distribution.

As a holistic approach, try a neural net, but use something to visualize the neurons and weights.  Letting the human visual cortex play with relationships can help extract subtle relationships.